# swift set first responder to text field but no cursor is visible

Tags: ios, swift

In my swift app, I have a text field, which by default is hidden.
When I press a button, the textfield should become visible and the cursor should be visible together on the keyboard. I am using the following code:

```
 textfield.hidden = false
 textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
```

The text field will become visible and the keyboard will be shown; however, the cursor is only visible if I press on the textfield with my finger.
Where is my error?

Comment: Are you sure ? Are you using simulator? try setting your window scale to 100%

Comment: Looks like you're doing it right.  If the keyboard shows, one of your textFields or textViews is the first responder.

Comment: i have the same issue on my iPhone 6s (not simulator). i can edit this textfield after it become first responder. but the cursor only will visible if i touch the textfield

Answer (score 0):

i also face the same problem ,i fixed by adding becomeFirstResponder in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad

`override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { passwordTxtField.becomeFirstResponder() }`

After that cursor appears within textfield,another possibility is your **Textfield** background color is similar to your ****TextField** Tint** Color,So changing TextField Tint Color Makes it works